# IBM MQ connection issue with pymqi

Tags: pymqi

Have got the following issue when trying to connect to ibm mq using pymqi from MAC OS Ventura 13.5.1 (22G90):
Python(88063,0x7ff856c31700) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff9558a2a70: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(88063,0x7ff856c31700) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
It was working for Ventura 13.4.1 before upgrading to 13.5.1.
$ dspmqver
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.3.2.0
Level:       p932-L230203.DE
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for macOS
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Darwin 22.6.0 [x86_64]
InstName:    MQNI93L23020300D
InstDesc:    IBM MQ V9.3.2.0 (Unzipped)
Primary:     N/A
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /Users/tjxz1/IBM/MQ/data
MaxCmdLevel: 932

Have tried to connect to IBM MQ and expect to get the connection queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for the issue and the steps to resolve on x86_64 MAC:

1. $export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/XXXX/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/tasks-dot-py/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clidriver/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. cp /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.5.0/lib/gcc/8/libstdc++.6.dylib /Users/XXXX/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/tasks-dot-py/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
3. $mv /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.5.0/lib/gcc/8/libstdc++.6.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@8/8.5.0/lib/gcc/8/libstdc++.6.dylib.backup